# Failed to connect to hbase from java

Tags: java, osx-lion, hbase

I've set up everything, like the hbase documentation says. Here is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class MainHBase {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
        try {
            HTable table = new HTable(config, "test-table");
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("test-key"));
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("q"), Bytes.toBytes("value"));
            table.put(put);
        } finally {
            admin.close();
        }
}
```

and here is the exception:

```
2012-12-26 11:08:07.980 java[10204:1c03] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.3-1240972, built on 02/06/2012 10:48 GMT
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=192.168.1.101
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0-ea
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/JDK 1.7.0 Developer Preview.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Documents/workspace/Hbase/bin:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/junit-4.10-HBASE-1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/libthrift-0.8.0.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/hbase-0.94.3-tests.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/hbase-0.94.3/hbase-0.94.3.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.asm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.aspects-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.context.support-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.expression-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.instrument-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.oxm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.test-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.transaction-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Downloads/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.web-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.aop-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.asm-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.aspects-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.beans-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.context-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.context.support-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.core-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.expression-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.instrument-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.jdbc-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.jms-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.orm-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.oxm-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.test-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.transaction-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.web.portlet-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.web.servlet-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Desktop/spring-framework-3.1.3.RELEASE/src/org.springframework.web.struts-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Downloads/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1-javadoc.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Downloads/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Downloads/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Downloads/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar:/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Downloads/commons-logging-1.1.1/commons-logging-tests.jar
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/_q/z5blmlxs39d4pmmv1fj9mh500000gn/T/
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=x86_64
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=10.7.5
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=urijvoskresenskij
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/Users/urijvoskresenskij
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/Users/urijvoskresenskij/Documents/workspace/Hbase
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /127.0.0.1:2181
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 10204@MacBook-Air-Urij.local
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will not SASL-authenticate because the default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
12/12/26 10:08:08 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13bd4823ba20007, negotiated timeout = 40000
12/12/26 10:08:08 WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Encountered problems when prefetch META table: 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in .META. for table: test-table, row=test-table,,99999999999999
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.access$000(MetaScanner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.execute(HConnectionManager.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:922)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:864)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:133)
    at MainHBase.main(MainHBase.java:20)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: test-table
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:864)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:133)
    at MainHBase.main(MainHBase.java:20)
```

Tried to google it already, but wasn't able to find the solution. My operating system is OS X. The table, that i've tried to create, cannot be scanned from hbase shell. Please, help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [hbase cannot find an existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586246/hbase-cannot-find-an-existing-table) - same root cause of `TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in .META`

Comment: No, sir, it's a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you created "test-table"?? table must exist before putting the data into it.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HBaseAdmin hbase = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor("test_table");
HColumnDescriptor cf = new HColumnDescriptor("cf".getBytes());
desc.addFamily(cf);
hbase.createTable(desc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And maybe you know, how to put data into it correctly??