# TableNotFoundException when connecting to a remote HBase instance

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, meta

I'm trying to connect to a remote hbase-0.94.8 installed on a ubuntu vm. I'm having a `TableNotFoundException` and this is my Java code:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.56.101");
HTableInterface usersTable = new HTable(config, "users");
```

Here is the full exception trace:

```
14/06/24 15:59:48 WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Encountered problems when prefetch META table: 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in .META. for table: users, row=users,,99999999999999
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:158)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.access$000(MetaScanner.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.execute(HConnectionManager.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:876)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:930)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:818)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:782)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:249)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
at com.heavenize.samples.hbase.UsersTool.main(UsersTool.java:37)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: users
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:952)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:818)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:782)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:249)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
at com.heavenize.samples.hbase.UsersTool.main(UsersTool.java:37)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586246/hbase-cannot-find-an-existing-table

Comment: It's not really duplicated because I'm not using hbase shell but rather the Java API. Also, when I use `hbase-0.98.3-hadoop2` I don't see this exception but the thread is blocked.

Comment: I figured out that the table should be created first, otherwise this exception is triggered. How I could ask HBase to create the table if not existent when I open the connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for table before using it. To do it you may use HBaseAdmin.
Create HBaseAdmin instance and thet use isTableAvailable(String tableName) method.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.56.101");
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
if(admin.isTableAvailable(tableName))
{
  HTableInterface usersTable = new HTable(config, "users");
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Is `new HTable(config, "users")` supposed create the table if not existent?