# HBase phantom table can't be created or deleted

Tags: linux, hadoop, hbase

As am trying to get familiar with hbase, I have created a table `example` in hbase shell. I reformatted the `NameNode` for hadoop and (because I didn't properly shut it down before my computer ran out of battery) restarted hadoop and hbase. But now I when I try to create `example` table I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Table already exists: example!
```

and when I try to disable it and drop it I get the following:

```
ERROR: Table example does not exist.
```

When I try to list the tables, no tables are listed. I even removed the hbase directory from hadoop, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hbase cannot find an existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586246/hbase-cannot-find-an-existing-table)

Comment: Nevermind. The solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586246/hbase-cannot-find-an-existing-table